# Limit ability to make global agent machine changes from within an Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

We've shot ourselves enough in the feet in various ways that we need a solution:

What is best practice for preventing an Azure DevOps pipeline from making global changes to an agent machine?

For example, a team created a pipeline that, for whatever reason, included a task that runs this command:

`git config --global http.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"`

This is obviously a very bad idea. If two pipelines are running on the same machine, they can cause each other unexpected behavior. If a pipeline runs this command without clearing the header that it set, then the machine is left in a permanent undesired state (and git 128 error is likely lurking).

We've seen similar global changes made in other tools such as docker.

In short, is there one or a few simple things that can be done to disallow these global machine changes from within a pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate you taking the time to share your thoughts. As of this time, however, the feature you required is not supported.

As a workaround, I suggest you submit a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). This is Microsoft's User Voice forum and the product team would consider your feedback seriously if it get enough votes.

Comment: One of our team members suggested that we could lock down particular files so that the agent service's user couldn't change them. Or, slightly different, have the agent user only be able to change files within the working directory but not outside the working directory. Would such an approach solve the problem?